# Variable evaluation fails in Eclipse when debugging JavaScript using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome-devtools

I have installed the *Chrome Dev Tools* Eclipse plug-in as described on http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/ and debugging JavaScript basically works. I can set breakpoints in my JavaScript source files and when I run the JavaScript code in Chrome, Eclipse stops the execution and opens the *Debug* perspective. Stepping through the code works fine, and I can also see the local and global variables in the *Variables* view.

When clicking on one of the variables, the detail view shows an error message, though:

```
Helper script failed on remote: _com_chromium_debug_helper is not defined
```

Did I miss something during the installation?

[image: Variables view with error]

**Update**

Added an issue on the project's page: http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you should open an issue at the project page. It is definitely a bug and fixing it might require additional context from you.

This is internals of ChromeDevTools SDK's workaround for WebKit Remote Debugging protocol limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=85